# Dynamic javascript using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is as follows:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var tagCounter=0;

    $("#tag-add-button").click(function () {
      var text = $("#tagadd").val();
        $("#set-tags").append("<input type='text' id='tag"+tagCounter+"' READONLY>");
      $("#tag"+tagCounter).val(text);
        $("#tagadd").val("");
        tagCounter++;
    });


});
</script>
```

This does the following:

When tag-add-button is clicked, it takes the text from the inputbox (tagadd) and puts it in a new inputbox thats appended to the set-tags div. The tagadd inputbox is then made blank.

The problem I'm having, is I want each input box to have its own remove button. But I don't see how the javascript can be generated for that when there can be an unlimited number of input boxes...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the input element **inside** of a div or span, and make the remove button a sibling of the input element. Then, in the onclick handler of the button, just do something like `$(this).parent().remove()`

This has the effect of removing both the input element, and the remove button itself

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using an id (`#tag-add-button`), use classes and then use the [each function](http://api.jquery.com/each/) of jQuery and traverse to the appropriate elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var tagCounter=0;

    $("#tag-add-button").click(function () {
        var text = $("#tagadd").val();
        $("#set-tags").append('<input type="text" id="tag'+tagCounter+'" READONLY /><span class="remove">Remove</span>');
        $("#tag"+tagCounter).val(text);
        $("#tagadd").val("");
        tagCounter++;
    });

    $('span.remove').bind('click',function(){
        $(this).prev('input').andSelf().remove();
    });


});
```

Comment: I'm trying this code, but nothing happens when I click "remove"

Comment: sorry replace 'bind' with 'live'